# React - Chrome does not report undefined JavaScript object property. Crashes

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome

Since im building my webapp with [React](https://reactjs.org/), when i try to set something into an undefined object property, the code processing crashes (reproducible with breakpoint debugging) and no errors are shown in the console log. Also the chrome react extension does not give me any errors.

So to finding a bug is more time consuming that it should be.

```
let changedJsonResponse = jsonResponse;
changedJsonResponse.data = newTableData; // changedJsonResponse.data is undefined

// throws no error & code proccess crashes
```

webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

let config = {
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    entry: {
        FooManagement: ['babel-polyfill', './domains/FooManagement/entry.jsx'],
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../web/react/'),
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    externals: {
        'jquery': 'window.jQuery',
        'bootbox': 'window.bootbox',
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            alias_shared: path.resolve(__dirname, 'shared'),
        },
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: [/node_modules/],
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {presets: ['es2015', 'react']}
            },
            {
                test: /\.css/,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
            }
        ]
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

package.json

```
{
  "author": "myself",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.jsx",
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "webpack -d --watch",
    "build": "webpack -p"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "dateformat": "^3.0.2",
    "is-uuid": "^1.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-cropper": "^1.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-dropzone": "^4.2.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-switchery-component": "0.0.7",
    "uuid": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

Chrome version: 62.0.3202.94

Comment: What is the error here `changedJsonResponse.data = newTableData;` ?

Comment: Okay, `changedJsonResponse.data` is undefined. If `changedJsonResponse` exists, like `{ }`, then this will work. Am I misunderstood you question?

Comment: Like i described in the code block, the property `data` is undefined. `// changedJsonResponse.data is undefined`. I noticed that the problem comes also when setting something into an undefined variable.

Comment: If `changedJsonResponse` is some object and `changedJsonResponse.data` is undefined then `changedJsonResponse.data = newTableData` will not throw any error.

Comment: @Prakashsharma Thats the problem. But it should throw an error, the code proccess is also halted then.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30709191/avoid-adding-methods-and-properties-to-custom-object

Comment: @JoshLee This has nothing to do with my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to catch those errors in Axios .catch.

After a while i found the [cause of the problem](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1103).